# const error = new Error("Validation failed, entered data is incorrect");

Tags: node.js

**Hello everyone,
I did a test and created an error on my input line 9 of my Postman, to see how my server handles this,
but my app crash because of my express-valitor that I misplaced on my index.js.

if anyone can help me please.
Thanks in advance**

```js
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index index.js`
Server is listening on : 3000
/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/controller/product.js:7
    const error = new Error("Validation failed, entered data is incorrect");
                  ^

Error: Validation failed, entered data is incorrect
    at createProduct (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/controller/product.js:7:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at middleware (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express-validator/src/middlewares/check.js:16:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  statusCode: 422
}

Node.js v18.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Hello everyone,
I did a test and created an error on my input line 9 of my Postman, to see how my server handles this,
but my app crash because of my express-valitor that I misplaced on my index.js.

if anyone can help me please.
Thanks in advance

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { SERVER_PORT, DB_PORT, DB_HOST } = require("./env");
// const products = require("./routes/product");
// const feedRoutes = require("./routes/feed");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});

require("./routes")(app);


app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("ERROR");
  const status = error.statusCode || 500;
  const message = error.message;
  const data = error.data;
  res.status(status).json({ message: message, data: data });
});

mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/CVshop`)
  .then((server) => {
    app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on : ${SERVER_PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

```js
const Product = require("../model/product");
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const createProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error("Validation failed, entered data is incorrect");
    error.statusCode = 422;
    // error.data = errors.array();
    throw error;
  }
  const admin = {
    _id: "62699cc64ae9329b383dbe71",
  };
  const product = new Product({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
    like: req.body.like,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    price: req.body.price,
    category: req.body.category,
    confirmDisplay: req.body.confirmDisplay,
    productsNumber: req.body.productsNumber,
    admin: admin,
  });
  console.log("Pduct: ", product);
  try {
    await product.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "Product created successfully!",
      data: product,
      creator: { _id: admin._id, name: "test" },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createProduct,
};
```

```js
const products = require("./product");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use("/product", products);
};
```

```js
// const router = require("express").Router();
const router = require("express").Router();
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const productController = require("../controller/product");

router.post(
  "/",
  [
    body("title", "Please enter a text end least 3 characters")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 3 })
      .isString(),
    body("description", "Please enter a text end least 6 characters")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 6 })
      .isString(),
    body("like", "Please enter a number").trim().isInt(),
    body("quantity", "Please enter a number").trim().isInt(),
    body("price", "Please enter a number").trim().toInt(),
    body("category", "Please enter a text end the requested categories")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 3 })
      .isString(),
    body(
      "confirmDisplay",
      "Please confirm the display true or false"
    ).isBoolean(),
    body("productsNumber", "Please enter a number").trim().isInt(),
  ],
  productController.createProduct
);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    like: {
      type: Number,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: [
        "clothes",
        "cars",
        "homeAppliance",
        "decorations",
        "computerScience",
        "books",
      ],
    },
    confirmDisplay: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    admin: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "admin",
    },
    productsNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productsSchema);
```

**

```js
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index index.js`
Server is listening on : 3000
/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/controller/product.js:7
    const error = new Error("Validation failed, entered data is incorrect");
                  ^

Error: Validation failed, entered data is incorrect
    at createProduct (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/controller/product.js:7:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at middleware (/Users/helderfernandes/ProjetPerso/CV_shop/cvShop/backend/node_modules/express-validator/src/middlewares/check.js:16:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  statusCode: 422
}

Node.js v18.2.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: what do you mean misplace it in index.js? the error created is because you created it in product.js if the errors from the validator were not empty

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).